# WPF DataTemplate and binding with TextBlock

Tags: wpf

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pointGroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ac:PointGroup}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tt2" DataType="{x:Type ac:PointGroup}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PointsCount}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

the first template works well with:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pointGroupTemplate}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"
                  Height="25" Margin="0,5,0,5">
```

but i want to use the second one in a textblock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding ElementName=comboBox1 ,Path=SelectedItem ?????}"/>
```

anyhelp.

Comment: Instead of a TextBlock, use `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tt2}" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}"/>`

Comment: @Clemens it works , thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a DataTemplate applied, you need a ContentPresenter or ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tt2}"
                Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox1}"/>
```